# How to create the grant total for AGG variable the table tableau dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

NUMBER OF OPPORTUNITY= count([opportunity id])

how to sum up the NO.of opportunity for each category
[image]

for example:
health grant total:8
commercial lines grant total: 9

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To display subtotals, choose Show all subtotals from the Analysis menu under Totals.

To calculate subtotals, you could use either a fixed or exclude LOD calculation. LOD calcs are described in the help and worth the time to understand.

Also, be sure you understand the difference between Count and Count Distinct. All count([xxx]) does is return the number of data rows that have a non-null value for the [xxx] field. If [xxx] is never null, that is the same as SUM([Number of Records])

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to explain with example as:
[image]
Your data is as per above example and you want totals of all region according to category wise.

**Here are the steps to execute.**

1.Go to analysis > totals > Total using subtotals and you will get results as  [image]

2.To get exact sum follow the steps as per below : [image]

Hope this will help.